# TFS 2015 Update 3 Build Deploy TestAgent Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' Keeps Rebooting and Does Not Finish

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, vnext

I have a vNext build that is stuck at the step below. The VM (Windows 10) keeps being rebooted (even after the build is manually stopped). This agent needs to be configured as an "Interactive Process" (to run Selenium tests).

> DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'DVDIP-W10-36.dev.jha:5985' is taking time. Please Wait

I see a lot of questions related to this problem that are unanswered. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happened to me and it was due to the fact there was a legal disclaimer that would appear prior to logging in that you had to click okay to dismiss.

To fix this, we had that legal disclaimer disabled for that machine.

**UPDATE**: Microsoft has addressed this in VSTS, TFS 2015.4, and TFS 2017.2 to cap the number of reboots at 3.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/07/03/deploy-visual-studio-test-agent-task-test-machine-rebooting-scenarios/

Comment: You meant the typical corporate policy that one has to acknowledge before being logged in?

Comment: Yeah - we had the powers that be update the group policy then did a GPUpdate /force from an admin command prompt on the machine.

Comment: I don't have permissions to modify Group Policies. Let me see if there's a way to disable it from the machine itself.

Comment: I presume the issue (at least in your case) is because the account (whatever it is) cannot acknowledge the legal disclaimer?

Comment: Correct.  I'm not sure there's anyway to make it acknowledge it either.

Essentially what is happening is a windows service is getting installed, it's trying to log in (since it's set to be an interactive process), getting stuck on that, and rebooting the machine.  The machine starts up again, service starts again, same problem.  The name of the windows service escapes me, but if you disable it, it should stop the constant rebooting.

Comment: I ended up installing the agent manually so the build can bypass this step. Not ideal but at least that can get it going for now. Thanks so much for your help!